# Connect to remote postgres server from EC2 Instance

Tags: postgresql, amazon-ec2, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to fetch data from the Postgres server which is remotely available from Amazon EC2 instance. When I try to telnet the remote server, it is connected.

But when I am running a kafka connector which connects to the remote Postgres server it throws an error stating

```
FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host, SSL off for configuration Couldn't open a connection to jdbc:postgresql://<url>
```

I tried changing the connection string from 
`jdbc:postgresql://host:5432/schema_name?user=******&password=******&defaultFetchSize=250000&useCursorFetch=true` 
to
 `jdbc:postgresql://host:5432/schema_name?ssl=true&user=******&password=******&defaultFetchSize=250000&useCursorFetch=true`

then it throws another error which is

`The server does not support SSL. for configuration Couldn't open a connection to jdbc:postgresql://<url>`

There is no SSL support in the Postgres server because I can connect to the server through any DB connector without ssh. I am sure it has to do something with the security access group of EC2(considering I can telnet to the server from the instance). Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like error is in the pg_hba.conf. I would have put this as a comment but not enough rep.

When you telnet to the server did you use the db port?

Can you post your pg_hba.conf file. This is one off my home dev server. You'll need to add a line similar to this: host    all             all             192.168.1.1/24          md5 with your IP addr and details.

If you're using this in a corporate network I'd highly recommend looking at a amazon VPC and not to expose your database to the internet.

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             10.10.187.1/24          md5
```

Comment: I have used DB port and it was connected.
And it was able to connect from other ec2 instances. As this is remote DB, we don't maintain it so we cannot edit pg_hba.conf file.